# How to identify each integer sequence regardless of ties in a vector

Tags: r, vector, sequence

This question is related to this [identify whenever values repeat in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71973162/identify-whenever-values-repeat-in-r/71973209#71973208)

While searching for answer there this new question arose:

I have this vector:

`vector <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3)`

I would like to identify each consecutive (by 1) integer sequence e.g. 1,2,3,.. or 3,4,5,.. or 4,5,6,7,...

**BUT**
It should allow **ties** 1,1,2,3,.. or 3,3,4,5,... or 4,5,5,6,6,7

The expected output would be a list like:

```
sequence1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 3)
sequence2 <- c(5, 6, 6, 7)
sequence3 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3)
```

So far the nearest approach I found here [Check whether vector in R is sequential?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506848/check-whether-vector-in-r-is-sequential), but could not transfer it to what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is with `diff` and `cumsum`

```
split(vector, cumsum(c(TRUE, abs(diff(vector)) > 1)))
```

-output

```
`1`
[1] 1 1 2 3

$`2`
[1] 5 6 6 7

$`3`
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 3 3
```